# Alphabetical controller initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initialization, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a controller `Admin::AddressController` that is a subclass of `AdminController`...and since "Address" comes before "Admin" I get a "uninitialized constant" error for the Admin Controller...

So to fix this, I've done a `require ./app/controllers/admin/AdminController.rb` before my AddressController class declaration.

Is the the right way to do things? Or is there a way I can tell rails to initialize the AdminController first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails should be able to handle that automatically if you're following the conventions. If you're placing AdminController inside the `admin` folder, the class should be named `Admin::AdminController`. It's either that or:

```
module Admin
  class AdminController
  ...
```

On AddressController you can use:

```
class Admin::AddressController < Admin::AdminController
...
```

or

```
module Admin
    class AddressControler < AdminController
...
```

Comment: Are you using this? `class Admin::AddressController < Admin::AdminController`

Comment: Happens to us all ;)

Comment: @KevinBrown make sure to accept the answer since it solved your issue.

Comment: No problem. Can you expand your answer some to help other Rails novices understand male spacing?